# Get image bytes

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsurl, nsbundle

I am trying to load the bytes of an image like this:

```
NSURL *img = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"img" ofType:@"png"] isDirectory:NO];
NSString * test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[img absoluteString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&err];
```

But I always get following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0xc02abf0 
{NSFilePath=file://localhost/Users/admin/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/C55551DB-152A-43D6-A1E0-9845105709D6/myApp.app/img.png,
 NSUnderlyingError=0xc02ccc0 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Folder or file does not exist"}
```

However the file DOES exist, and if I copy/paste the NSFilePath into the browser it finds the image. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathforResource:@"img" ofType:"png"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You can't just store random bytes in an NSString - it will try to convert them into a string and might fail. You need to use an NSData object for binary data.

You also don't need to use NSURLs at all; `NSBundle` will give you a path as a string.

Comment: Actually, depending on what you want, @beryllium has a good answer as well! With my answer you are not only going to get the bytes of the image, you're going to get all the extra stuff a .png file has - beryllium's answer _only_ gives you the image data.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the file URL, use `[img path]` instead of `[img absoluteString]` in the second line.

Or use `[NSURL URLWithPath]` in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Store bytes in NSData:

```
NSData *bytes = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation("imagename.."); //the image is converted to bytes
```

Comment: This won't even compile :( `UIImagePNGRepresentation` takes a `UIImage *`, not a `char*` - look at @beryllium's answer for what you're trying to do.